# Export products from Magento 1.6 and import products in Magento 2.0.9

Tags: magento2, product, import, export

I need to import lots of configurable products to my new Magento 2. But if I export a CSV File and import in Magento 2 I get 1000s of errors.

The File is different than a CSV I export from Magento 2. SKU are missing, categories are different and much more.

What is the best way to get products from Magento 1 to Magento 2? I don't want to migrate the whole shop, only the products.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

```
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-data.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html
```

This will hep you migrate whole system from magento 1 to magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Please change max_execution_time = 18000 in php.ini or .htaccess

you should import in local

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should try another way. First of all, please upgrade your Magento version, you can upgrade Website in 2 instances one from Composer and Another from Manual Way(Downloaded form Magento Website).

- If you choose a composer update, you can consult this document from Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html
- If you choose manual way, you need to set up a new Magento version and copy the entire informations from your old version to the new one - You can do it manually one by one or export to CSV file then import into your new website.

After successfully upgraded, you need to find experienced migration experts to help you migrate data such as products, categories and orders from your old store on Magento 1 to Magento 2 smoothly, quickly and safely. This solution save you a lot of time and effort.